# How can I export a file (.xlsx) from NODE JS that contains a million rows and "N" columns?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, export-to-excel, xlsx

I have to export a file that contains a million rows and  colums "N", I could not find the way to export such amount of data in a file (.xlsx), does anyone have any idea if there is an API that allows me to export such quantity.?

Comment: Rather than xlsx, create a CSV instead (Comma Separated Values). These are lightweight, easy to create and can be opened by any spreadsheet reader.

Comment: Too broad question... [create a read stream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) and pipe it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One million? where do you work? you have to try some pagination of some sort, `[data splitting]` there is a free l[ibrary](http://sheetjs.com/pro) which can help you export from json, csv, etc, if this is about migration, do rephrase your question

Comment: Thank you very much, this library was perfect for what I needed.